# Where are the application crash files stored?

Tags: apport, error-handling, ubuntu-bug

I experience instability with my Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. I receive messages

> Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experiences an internal error. If you notice
>   further problems, try restarting the computer

The messages show up a few times per day but they not associated with the same application. Today I have one with `/usr/share/screenlets/screenlets-pack-basic/Sysmonitor/SysmonitorScreenlet.py` and another one is `/usr/bin/vlc`. I would like to solve the problem, but at first I want to save the details of each warning to track underlying problem.

I cannot find any way to save details of this warning and cannot find, if they are saved somewhere on the system as a log. I cannot highlight few lines at ones, and if I try to copy a line, it does not work.

Is there a way to save the details of these errors?

Comment: If I am not wrong, the crash logs are stored in `/var/crash`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I am not wrong, the crash logs are stored in `/var/crash`.

-[jokerdino](https://askubuntu.com/users/25798/jokerdino) at [14:10 UTC on 11-11-2012](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215764/saving-an-internal-error-details#comment267209_215764)

These logs can be transported and saved. If if references a data file, it may be of help to save that file for reference.

Comment: You.. you just didn't do that.

Comment: @jokerdino I did... But I will *always* make it community wiki and remove it once needed.